How can one estimate the average part size of a partition of a set with random sampling?
I am sure this is a simple question, but I have no experience with statistics. Say we have some set $X$ whose size $n = |X|$ is known. $X$ is divided into $j$ (disjoint) parts $p_i$, but we do not know $j$ nor anything about this partition.
Suppose that if we randomly select $x \in X$, we can determine the size of the part $p_i$ containing $x$. How can we use this sampling to estimate the number $j$ of parts of $X$, or, alternatively, the average size of a part?
I know that simply averaging the sizes of the parts from the samples will over-represent the larger parts: $X = [1] \cup [2] \cup [3,4,...,100]$ consists of $3$ parts of average size $33.3$, but the naive sampling would estimate an average size near $98$. What is the right way to do this? Thanks.
Follow-up question: assume further that once we've sampled $x \in X$, we can determine not only the size of the part containing $x$, but also all other elements in that part. Does this change anything?

Take the case where there are two partitions of size 50, $X_1=[1,...,50]$ and $X_2=[51,...,100]$. Suppose the first two draws are $x=1$ and $x_2=51$. In your main question, we would just know that both draws come from a set of size 50, so they could potentially come from the same set. And after two draws, there is still a possibility that there are 51 total sets (one set of size 50 and 50 sets of size one). In the follow-up, you would already know that there are only two sets and they both have size = 50.

Terminology: When you say partition, the usual terminology would be part, the union of all the $j$ parts being the partition. Care to edit? Question: Can you sample with/without replacement? Is sampling expensive?

@kjetilbhalvorsen Fixed. I suppose we could sample with/without replacement. It is expensive to determine the size of the part $p_i$ containing $x$ (the larger, the more expensive).

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture does this apply to your case?

Describing the sample data: First it is useful to describe the nature of the observeable data that you are referring to in your question.  Given a fixed set $\mathcal{X}$, for any given partition $\mathscr{X}$ on the set, and any given vector of values $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,...,x_n)$ sampled from the set, we can define the vector function of corresponding values:
$$\mathbf{s} \equiv \mathbf{s}(\mathbf{x},\mathscr{X}) \equiv (s_1,...,s_n)$$
with individual values given by:
$$s_k \equiv \sum_{\mathcal{E} \in \mathscr{X}} \mathbb{I}(x_k \in \mathcal{E}) \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{I}(x_i \in \mathcal{E}).$$
Each element $s_k$ gives the number of sample values that are in the same partition piece as $x_k$ (which is always at least one, since $x_k$ must be in its own partition piece).  Based on your description, there is some sampling mechanism for $\mathbf{x}$ and we observe the resulting piecewise count vector $\mathbf{s}$.  Based on this, we wish to make an inference about the unknown partition $\mathscr{X}$.

The piecewise count vector in this problem is a deterministic function of the sample vector and the unknown partition.  Suppose we define the set of all possible sample vectors $\mathbf{x}$ that are consistent with the observed piecewise count vector $\mathbf{r}$ under the partition $\mathscr{X}$.  This is denoted by:
$$\mathscr{D}(\mathbf{r},\mathscr{X}) \equiv \{ \mathbf{x} | \mathbf{s}(\mathbf{x},\mathscr{X}) = \mathbf{r} \}.$$
Suppose we have some underlying sampling mechanism that gives a distribution with sampling density $p(\mathbf{x}) \equiv \mathbb{P}(\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{x})$.  (We will assume that the sample vector is independent of the partition choice for $\mathscr{X}$.)  Then using the law of total probability we have the sampling density:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{S}=\mathbf{s}|\mathscr{X})
&= \sum_{\mathbf{x}} \mathbb{P}(\mathbf{S}=\mathbf{s}|\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{x},\mathscr{X}) \cdot \mathbb{P}(\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{x}) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{\mathbf{x}} \mathbb{P}(\mathbf{S}=\mathbf{s}|\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{x},\mathscr{X}) \cdot p(\mathbf{x}) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathscr{D}(\mathbf{s},\mathscr{X})} p(\mathbf{x}). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
This gives you the sampling density for the problem, which gives the likelihood function (taken as a function of $\mathscr{X}$ instead of $\mathbf{s}$).  You could apply classical estimation methods or estimate using Bayesian analysis with a prior.  For the latter, given a prior distribution $\pi$ for the partition, we have the resulting posterior distribution:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\mathscr{X}|\mathbf{S}=\mathbf{s})
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{S}=\mathbf{s}|\mathscr{X}) \cdot \pi(\mathscr{X})}{\sum_{\mathscr{X}} \mathbb{P}(\mathbf{S}=\mathbf{s}|\mathscr{X}) \cdot \pi(\mathscr{X})} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{[\sum_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathscr{D}(\mathbf{s},\mathscr{X})} p(\mathbf{x})] \cdot \pi(\mathscr{X})}{\sum_{\mathscr{X}} [\sum_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathscr{D}(\mathbf{s},\mathscr{X})} p(\mathbf{x})]  \cdot \pi(\mathscr{X})}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Thanks for the explanation. It seems that piecewise counter vector $s$ can only be constructed if we can determine, for instance, whether two sample values $x_a, x_b$ are in the same partition piece. What analysis is possible when we can only tell the size of the partition each $x_a$ is in (and not compare membership)?

@healnyr: Sure, it can only be constructed that way from the underlying elements in the partition, but I understand your question to be one where you observe $\mathbf{s}$ directly and you don't know the underlying vector $\mathbf{x}$ that generated it.  So the present answer does not assume that you know anything about $\mathbf{x}$ beyond the fact that it must be copatible with the observed $\mathbf{s}$.  In particular, I don't assume that you can tell whether sample valus are in the same partition piece or not.  You can infer that but not observe it (if I've understood your problem).

Your question reminds me of spectral clustering and finding the correct clustering (the correct partition)
Potentially just see this as a long comment for the case where you cannot fully obtain ground truth about the size of a part/cluster but have to estimate this from samples of the adjacency matrix (this is different to your assumptions)
Let's say you have a set of instances which you want to cluster. Each cluster would be a part to which an instance belongs.
I performed some simulations (assuming equal clusters of size x) with total number of instances y and then you can run simulations about how many samples of pairs of instances you need to draw to get the expected number of connected components y/x right (e.g. with networkx https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/component.html )
In my simulations it was ~10% of pairs to be sampled in order to correctly reconstruct the number of connected components (parts) (out of $1/2 y(y-1)$ possible pairs in the adjacency matrix which denotes if two instances are in the same cluster? yes/no). Now this clearly depends on the equal cluster size assumption, but maybe this gives you another perspective.
